# assembly code explaination

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

its a program which prints hello world 
i am newbie in assembly and i was reading Reverse engineering for beginners (the code belongs there )
i am just confused

what is

1. var_10 = dword ptr -10h
2. why and esp and 0fff.... ?
3. what is happening in mov [esp+10h+var_10], eax ?

and .... :)))
 i would be appreciative if some one explain it in more detail

thnx

---

```
main proc near
var_10 = dword ptr -10h
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub esp, 10h
mov eax, offset aHelloWorld ; "hello, world"
mov [esp+10h+var_10], eax
call _printf
mov eax, 0
leave
retn
main endp
```

and another question that i have  ive seen a lot things like this `$SG3830 DB ’a=%d; b=%d; c=%d’, 00H`  what is it doing ?  what is 00H ?

Comment: 1. It's creating an _equate_ (a compile-time constant) with the name `var_10`. 2. It's aligning the stack to a 16 byte boundary.

Comment: @Michael  i think i ve got problems with hexadecimal ! relationshio of  0fffffff0h with 16 ?

Comment: It masks out the 4 least significant bits, which means that the least significant bit that can remain set after that operation is bit 4. 2^4 == 16, so the result is guaranteed to be a multiple of 16.

Comment: @Michael: comments are not answers

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: I didn't feel that my explanations were detailed enough to be called an answer, hence I posted them as comments instead. If someone else wants to write a proper answer, go ahead.

Answer (score 4):

To understand the text below, one should understand the concept of frame pointer, which is esp before making room for variables with sub esp,....

The framepointer is typically stored in ebp, but often omitted for small functions, like in this code. The value in this code is esp+10h, since 0x10h is subtracted from esp to make room for local variables.

Parameters have positive offsets relative to the framepointer, local variables negative offsets relative to the framepointer.

1. calculating an offset for a local variable relative to the frame pointer. It doesn't help for the overview that the code doesn't use a frame pointer.
2. esp and 0xFFF0 aligns the stack on a 16 byte boundary, a requirement for many runtimes nowadays (due to SSE2). Note that the subtracted value one instruction later subtracts 0x10 again, which is probably the space for local variables rounded up to a multiple of 16 (0x10) to keep the alignment.

   If all functions maintain alignment, it should not be strictly required to check this in every function, so this function is defensively programmed. (maybe because it is exported or used as a callback?)
3. access the local variable for read (value to eax), var10 is the offset relative to that framepointer